# How to provide and use command line arguments in docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile as shown below:

```
FROM centos:centos6
MAINTAINER tapash

######  Helpful utils
RUN yum -y install sudo
RUN yum -y install curl
RUN yum -y install unzip

#########Copy hibernate.cfg.xml to Client

ADD ${hibernate_path}/hibernate.cfg.xml /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/roc_client/WEB-INF/classes/
```

I need a command line argument to be passed during docker build to be specified for the $hibernate_path.

How do I do this?

Comment: Dear negative voter..let me know what's wrong with the question?

Comment: This will not work. The docker file is only read one time, when you build your image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is purely a build-time variable, you can use the [`--build-arg option of docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg).

> This flag allows you to pass the build-time variables that are accessed like regular environment variables in the `RUN` instruction of the Dockerfile. Also, these values don’t persist in the intermediate or final images like `ENV` values do.

```
docker build --build-arg hibernate_path=/a/path/to/hibernate -t tag .
```

---

In 1.7, only the static [`ENV` Dockerfile directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) is available.
So one solution is to generate the Dockerfile you need from a template Dockerfile.tpl.

```
Dockerfile.tpl:

...
ENV hibernate_path=xxx
ADD xxx/hibernate.cfg.xml /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/roc_client/WEB-INF/classes/
...
```

Whenever you want to build the image, you generate first the Dockerfile:

```
sed "s,xxx,${hibernate_path},g" Dockerfile.tpl > Dockerfile
```

Then you build normally: `docker build -t myimage .`

You then benefit from (in docker 1.7):

- build-time environment *substitution*
- run-time environment variable.

Comment: Tried this. Says  :  flag provided but not defined: --build-arg
See 'docker build --help'.

Comment: You must have docker 1.9 or 1.10

Comment: Hm..I'm using docker 1.7. Any options?

Comment: Yes: upgrade. 1.7 is obsolete.

Comment: That is why build-arg has been introduced in 1.9. Because that was not possible before.

Comment: Ok..how about adding command line arguments at docker run.I want to try using docker run -e and set a ENV variable value. But how to refer to that variable in build time?

Comment: On build time, that is what build-arg is for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104237/discussion-between-priyanka-patil-and-vonc).

Comment: Now i want to just build it without specifying argument at command line
Later during run time..
I want to use
docker run -e hibernate_path="Some path" image_name
If i do intend to do this, docker build fails
Throws this error
Step 26 : ADD $HIBERNATE_PATH/hibernate.cfg.xml /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/roc_client/WEB-INF/classes/ 
hibernate.cfg.xml: no such file or directory
My requirement is now to defer command-line at docker run time
can you help?

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil ADD is not "runtime". It is build-time. Hence the need of build-arg.

Comment: Oh..Ok..then I think my not relevant here..then is there a way to specify the value of variable at runtime?. I will be referencing that variable in Dockerfile.The docker build should not be affected.

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil yes: ENV (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env, available in 1.7). You declare it in the Dockerfile, and it will be available at runtime.

Comment: Yes.But ENV takes two args, key and value. Both have to be provided in Dockerfile and hence be available at build time, where as in my case ,value will be available at docker run time as a command line arg.

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil OK. I have edited the answer with a workaround allowing you to benefit from the `$hibernate_path` environment variable *both* at build-time *and* run-time! And with docker 1.7.

Comment: Serves the purpose.Yet, the value need to be given before build time. Isn't it? I want to encapsulate the docker build from the users and expose only docker run .

Comment: @Priyanka.Patil not exactly "given". All you need is the environment variable `$hibernate_path` to be set before calling any docker build command (or any wrapper script)

Comment: Well. certainly a solution, but not what i'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You create a script that puts in your Dockerfile the required value and launches `docker build -t mytag .`